# SharePoint 2013 how to update repeating data on weekly basis

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, sharepoint-server

In a new SharePoint 2013 project that I am working on, the user will be entering the same data on a weekly basis. The data will need to be entered between a start date and end date. The required columns  will be the same every week but the data entered on a weekly basis should change.

Thus can you tell me how I could display and save the data that the user enters on a weekly basis. Would I enter a little information in a 'master' record and all the 'repeating' rows be details in a 'master/detail' web part?

Thus I would really appreciate your suggestion on how I can display and/or store the data that is entered weekly by the user?

Comment: You can probably set the default values to the known fields. So user can leave it blank.

Answer (score 1):

I would edit the list in InfoPath. There is a lot you can do with repeating sections, required logic and show/hide logic in there.

Comment: Would you tell me and/or point me to links InfoPath 2013 that shows how to 'There is a lot you can do with repeating sections, required logic and show/hide logic in there'?

Comment: What you are referring to in InfoPath, does that work with the details in a master/detail relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If the pre-filled data is pre-determined for the date range, you could setup a lookup list that has start date, end date and field value. Then you could create a worlflow that checks the created date of your new items is greater than or equal to the start date in your lookup and less than or equal to the end date in the lookup. Then update predefined fields with the predefined data in the lookup list on items that fall in that date range.

You would just have to remember to update your lookup list with the next weeks values and date range, prior to the week of for it to update correctly. I'm also assuming that the same columns are being updated with this data.